# Why all deformations of the string background come from vertex operators?

Tags: string-theory

It is possible to ask for deformations of the string action that preserve conformal (or superconformal) symmetry. These are the integrated vertex operators.

Two questions:

- Is there a reason -- physical or mathematical -- why these vertices are deformations of the string background?
- Is it possible to obtain a deformation of the background (integrated vertex operator) that does not come from the BRST cohomology (unintegrated vertex operators)?

Comment: yes to both, but i don’t have time to elaborate in detail: 2. roughly speaking, background deformations come from string loops (which are offshell contributions), so the corresponding deformations do not live in the brst cohomology unless the background satisfies classical equations of motion. 1. vertex operators by which you deform the action originate in bilocal operators that create handles on your riemann surface, and these are precisely composed of offshell vertex operators.